# What try could do in a php file?

Tags: php

After a long php file related to a rest api i do have these following line can anyone helps me what they do really and what try in php does.

```
if (!array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {

    $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}

try {

    $API  = new MyAPI($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_REQUEST, $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);

    $METH = $API->processAPI();

    echo $METH;

} catch (Exception $e) {

    $METH = json_encode(Array('error' => $e->getMessage()));

    echo $METH;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
  //...code 1...
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  //...code 2...
}
```

The try-catch-block combination is used for Exception handling. What that means is the following... If something "bad" happens in `//...code 1...`, instead of your program crashing and stopping all together, your code knows that it should jump to the `catch` block and continue executing commands from there.

It is very good practice to use try-catch-blocks in your code because it helps you control what your code should do in case something goes wrong. Something that is often found in `//...code 2...` is the creation of Logs that give the programmer information on what could have possibly caused the error in `//...code 1...`.

Let me know if that helped you! :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but thought try is executing the function and when errors happens ti goes to catch exception ! am i getting wrong logic ? so where you think the success json could be declared and returned ?

Comment: @jaylab If I understood you correctly in your previous argument, your logic is then correct. I'm not sure what you are referring to with "success json". Also, if this answer helped you with your question, please accep the answer (green check mark) so that future users know that it worked for you :)

Comment: in other meaning this line the echo in catch cold return a success variable for an example an json response or only it is echoing an error ! i got confused when you told me that try and catch both echo errors related logs!

Comment: @jaylab it is echoing an error! In this line: `$METH = json_encode(Array('error' => $e->getMessage()));` you can see `$e->getMessage()`. and `echo $METH;` is echoing that error!

Comment: still getting confused this line what could potentialy echoes 

    $API  = new MyAPI($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_REQUEST, $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);

    $METH = $API->processAPI();

    echo $METH;

Comment: @jaylab I have to go. If my answer helped you , please give a green checkmark to it so other users know it is the accepted answer